# How do calculate a specific row of CSV data in python?

Tags: python, csv

I have a set of CSV data, and I need to calculate the total quantity and profit using Visual studio code. A group of codes have already been provided for me, hence I need to do the calculation. Only the profit in Column N (row 13) and quantity in Column O (row 14) should be part of the calculation.
[the data in CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tbO8.png)

this is the code provided for me:

```
fp = Path.cwd()/"superstore_transaction.csv"
with fp.open(mode="r", encoding="UTF-8", newline="") as file:
reader = csv.reader(file)
next(reader)
cluster1 = [] 
cluster2 = []
cluster3 = []
for row in reader:
            
    if row[4] == "Cluster 1":
        cluster1.append([row[13], row[14]])
    elif row[4] == "Cluster 2":
        cluster2.append([row[13], row[14]])
    else:
        cluster3.append([row[13], row[14]])
```

I tried using For loop, but it doesn't work. I think in general I am just confused with the overall coding that was already provided for me, and I am only limited to a number of codes that I can use to help calculate the total profit

Comment: Please add your code snippet and your file sample as text not images

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `profit` column have percentage values, so you need to remove the `%` symbol so it can be converted to a `int` or `float` values for the calculation.

Here is an example of `cluster1`, so you do the same for others manually or looping through them as you want :

```
cluster1_profit = sum(float(sub_c1[0].replace('%', '')) for sub_c1 in cluster1)
cluster1_quantity = sum(int(sub_c1[1]) for sub_c1 in cluster1)
```

For this I just did the sum of profits and quantities, so it depends on how you want to calculate your total.

There are better ways to do this, using [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) or [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), it will make it easier.